# Bootstrap inline form is not responsive on low width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have done a inline form using bootstrap. It don't work responsive if I try to minimize or shrink the width of browser. Not sure but are boot strap inline forms not responsive ? Controls just jumbled with each other. I cant change design of page. Kindly guide how I can correct this to work not jumbled and responsive in a clean and clear way.

Form in full width when it is ok:
[image]

Form in minimize browser or when screen width is reduced:
[image]

Here is my Markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    Round:
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="roundNumber"  value="<%= Model.Round %>" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-green" onclick="displayRound()" value="Display">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-green" onclick="exportHistory()" value="Export history"></div>        
</div>
```

Comment: I'm confused, this isn't anything like the markup that Bootstrap provides for inline forms? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms What are you expecting to happen??

Comment: @davidpauljunior as I explained in my question, on low width controls got mixed (jumbled) with each other. They are not separate and properly aligned as bootstrap provide by default. I want to fix it.

Comment: @davidpauljunior in your example see inline form and try to reduced width of page slowly. It is responsive but in my image they just got jumbled.

Comment: They're not jumbled, they're sat on top of each other because on small devices `col-md-*` doesn't have a width specified, so it's a full width `<div>`.  Either, use the markup Bootstrap suggest, or try using the class `col-xs-4` instead of `col-md-4`

Comment: @davidpauljunior thanks it is better but how I can make them coming to different lines as other bootstrap pages do ? Even in your example as well. By your markup it work fine on lower screen but shorter to that again they are rendered on each other. Please advice

Comment: Also, they go off to the left because you have next columns without giving them a parent `.row`.
I don't see these ever render on each other...http://jsbin.com/rubot/1/edit

Answer (score 5):

You may wish to use the class prefix .col-xs- instead of md [Grid Options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="col-xs-3">Round:</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="roundNumber" value="<%= Model.Round %>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-green" onclick="displayRound()" value="Display">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-green" onclick="exportHistory()" value="Export history">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Burms thanks it is better but how I can make them coming to different lines as other bootstrap pages do ? Even in your example as well. By your markup it work fine on lower screen but shorter to that again they are rendered on each other. Please advice

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by making them come to different lines, can you rephrase your question?

Comment: I think this approach is more effective