# Bootstrap fixed footer with text box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying complex responsive webpage.

Here I used bootstrap footer class with simple feedback input inside. I am following bootstrap example documentation. Why footer does not stick to bottom and text box seems misaligned?

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/6eccwwsc/3/

```
<footer class="footer" >
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-muted">@Copyright</p>        
        <div class="form-group">
          <input placeholder="Email" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Subscribe</button>

  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed footer, you can use

```
footer{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}
```

And for form inline, check out this, its somehow similar to your problem.
[Bootstrap inline form is not responsive on low width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056293/bootstrap-inline-form-is-not-responsive-on-low-width)

Comment: thanks dude, could you please help puting login box similar to search box in header in this link bootsnipp.com/tags/navbar

Comment: can you just make it on jsfiddle or jsbin for detailed.

Comment: here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/0c9sL86z/1/  issue now is, footer expands outof container on right side, feedback button and text does not appear in bottom bar

Answer (score 1):

Fixed to bottom

Add .navbar-fixed-bottom and include a .container or .container-fluid to center and pad navbar content.

from documentation http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Comment: thanks dude, could you please help puting login box similar to search box in header in this link http://bootsnipp.com/tags/navbar

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/6eccwwsc/4/

```
footer{
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: thanks dude, could you please help puting login box similar to search box in header in this link http://bootsnipp.com/tags/navbar